# Name mangaling of static objects

Tags: c++, static-members, dynamic-linking, name-mangling

I came across [this article on dynamic linking](https://github.com/bartgrantham/dynamic-libraries-in-c-and-cpp-article/blob/master/README.md) in C++.

We can create a C++ factory which would return an object of the class we are interested.
Also, we should create a static object in file scope for the factory so that it can be located using `dlsym()`. (The article suggests that static objects are not name mangled.)

Why are static objects not name mangled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name mangling is invented to assist in resolving overloaded function names. You can define several functions with the same name, differing only in the count and the types of their parameters. Name mangling lets the linker resolve such functions to the correct place in the code.

Unlike names of functions, names of static objects in the global namespace cannot be overloaded, so mangling them is not necessary. Names of objects that are outside of global namespace are, in fact, mangled.

Comment: Object names can and in fact are mangled, because of namespaces. However, the question is specifically about "static" objects at file scope (i.e. in the global namespace) in which case the mangling may very well be a no-op.

Comment: @MSalters Thank you very much for a great comment! I fixed the answer to clarify that only names of objects in the global namespace are not mangled.